# How can I check how many .Net applications are installed on a Windows system?

Tags: .net, windows

I am reading Applied Microsoft .NET Framework Programming by Jeffrey Richter.

I was wondering what is the conveninent way to find out how many .Net applications are installed on a Windows system.

Can you advise?

Thanks!

Comment: what about those application deployed with XCopy deployment? those green apps which do not change anything in the registry and do not list in the Installed Programs in Control Panel. You won't catch those...

Comment: Uninstall the .net Framework and count how many error messages pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

This will be nearly impossible to find out. How do you know, how many *normal* applications are installed? What of applications, partly written in DotNet? Is a library written in DotNet an application or not?

Comment: Let alone applications that are not installed but just are an 'exe' you could run.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a program that runs through the disk and scan for .EXEs file, trying to determine if ther are .NET or native. Here is a piece of C# code that can determine if a file is a .NET file (DLL or EXE):

```
public static bool IsDotNetFile(string filePath)
{
    if (filePath == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filePath");

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            if (br.ReadUInt16() != 0x5A4D) // IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE
                return false;

            byte[] bytes = new byte[112]; // max size we'll need
            const int dosHeaderSize = (30 - 1) * 2; // see IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
            if (br.Read(bytes, 0, dosHeaderSize) < dosHeaderSize)
                return false;

            fs.Seek(br.ReadUInt32(), SeekOrigin.Begin);
            if (br.ReadUInt32() != 0x4550) // IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE
                return false;

            // get machine type
            ushort machine = br.ReadUInt16(); // see IMAGE_FILE_HEADER

            br.Read(bytes, 0, 20 - 2); // skip the rest of IMAGE_FILE_HEADER

            // skip IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER
            if (machine == 0x8664) //IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64
            {
                br.Read(bytes, 0, 112); // IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64
            }
            else
            {
                br.Read(bytes, 0, 96); // IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32
            }

            // skip 14 data directories, and get to the IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_COM_DESCRIPTOR, the 15th one
            br.Read(bytes, 0, 14 * 8);

            // if the COR descriptor size is 0, it's not .NET
            uint va = br.ReadUInt32();
            uint size = br.ReadUInt32();
            return size > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It's based on PE standard file format analysis, but focuses only on .NET determination. See more on this here: [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985992.aspx)